# Java applet load once under apache

Tags: java, apache, applet

Java applet self-signed load corectly when call from explorer (file://...test.htm).
When the same html file is called under apache, the applet load correctly the first time (after cleaning all caches).
This is the log from the java console when applet load correctly :

```
cache: Initialize resource manager: com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl@f522e8
security:  --- parseCommandLine converted : -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
into:
[-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true]
basic: Processus d'écoute de progression ajouté : sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@1ad080f
security: Expected Main URL: http://portail-rep/LanceAppli.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://portail-rep/LanceAppli.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://portail-rep/LanceAppli.jar
network: Entrée de cache introuvable [URL : http://portail-rep/LanceAppli.jar, version : null]
network: Connexion de http://portail-rep/LanceAppli.jar avec proxy=DIRECT
network: Connexion de http://portail-rep:80/ avec proxy=DIRECT
network: Téléchargement de la ressource : http://portail-rep/LanceAppli.jar
    Content-Length : 4 058
    Content-Encoding : null
network: URL http://portail-rep/LanceAppli.jar enregistrée dans le fichier C:\Users\damien\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\22\133a80d6-16383b84-temp
security: La vérification de révocation de la liste noire est activée
security: blacklist: Reconstruct cache
security: blacklist: created: NEED_CREATE, lastModified: 1399896272579
security: blacklist: check contains qx2NE11fDtlcwJoPYN21GqqZVuP5NiFAD+fWu7Hqf1g=, state now NEED_CREATE
security: blacklist: check raw C:\Users\damien\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\blacklist.dynamic, false
security: blacklist: check raw C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\security\blacklist, false
security: blacklist: check raw C:\Users\damien\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\blacklist, false
security: blacklist: save cache to C:\Users\damien\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\security\blacklist.cache
security: La vérification de liste de bibliothèques sécurisées est activée
security: Fichier de liste de bibliothèques sécurisées non trouvé
cache: Create from verifier: JarSigningData{hasOnlySignedEntries=true, hasSingleCodeSource=true, hasMissingSignedEntries=false}
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: http://portail-rep/LanceAppli.jar
security: Sécurisation pour : http://portail-rep/LanceAppli.jar terminée : Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970
security: Accès aux clés et au certificat dans le profil utilisateur Mozilla : null
security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: http://portail-rep/LanceAppli.jar
security: Chargement des certificats de déploiement depuis C:\Users\damien\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.certs
security: Certificats de déploiement chargés depuis C:\Users\damien\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.certs
security: Chargement des certificats depuis la banque de déploiement des certificats de session
security: Certificats chargés depuis la banque de déploiement des certificats de session
security: Chargement des certificats depuis la banque de déploiement des certificats de session
security: Certificats chargés depuis la banque de déploiement des certificats de session
security: Chargement des certificats depuis la banque de déploiement des certificats de session
security: Certificats chargés depuis la banque de déploiement des certificats de session
security: Chargement des certificats depuis la banque de déploiement des certificats de session
security: Certificats chargés depuis la banque de déploiement des certificats de session
security: Valider la chaîne de certificats à laide de lAPI CertPath
security: Chargement des certificats CA racine depuis C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\security\cacerts
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1399896272623 (we have 1399896272579)
network: Thread de nettoyage utilisé 202028 us
security: Certificats CA racine chargés depuis C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\security\cacerts
security: Obtenir la collection de certificats de la banque des certificats CA racine
security: Obtenir la collection de certificats de la banque des certificats CA racine
security: Obtenir la collection de certificats de la banque des certificats CA racine
security: Obtenir la collection de certificats de la banque des certificats CA racine
security: Loading blacklisted.certs file: C:\Users\damien\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\blacklisted.certs
security: SHA-256Certificate finger print: FF7707AFD64E63FF1040A4476AD697C8451B151623FA88007D25A74ACEC935F2
security: La prise en charge du protocole OCSP est activée.
security: La prise en charge de la liste des certificats révoqués (CRL) est activée.
security: Enregistrement des certificats dans la banque de déploiement des certificats de session
security: Certificats enregistrés dans la banque de déploiement des certificats de session
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.05
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.05
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.05
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.05
basic: Dialog type is not candidate for embedding
security: Lutilisateur a accordé les privilèges au code pour cette session seulement
security: Enregistrement des certificats dans la banque de déploiement des certificats de session
security: Certificats enregistrés dans la banque de déploiement des certificats de session
security: SHA-256Certificate finger print: FF7707AFD64E63FF1040A4476AD697C8451B151623FA88007D25A74ACEC935F2
security: Decision time stored for ai: Appinfo:
type = 2
title = LanceAppli
vendor = null
from = http://portail-rep/LanceAppli.jar
security = 0
lapURL = http://portail-rep//apExec
appArgs = ##docbase:http://portail-rep/test.htm##Parameters:{id=apExec, height=300, __applet_relaunched=false, java_arguments=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true, name=apExec, width=300, cache_option=Plugin, archive=LanceAppli.jar, code=irsn/LanceAppli.class, cache_archive=LanceAppli.jar, type=application/x-java-applet, classid=java:irsn/LanceAppli.class, codebase=http://portail-rep/}
security: Grant socket perm for http://portail-rep/LanceAppli.jar : java.security.Permissions@b9f649 (
 ("java.net.SocketPermission" "portail-rep" "connect,accept,resolve")
)

security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: http://portail-rep/LanceAppli.jar
security: Valider la chaîne de certificats à laide de lAPI CertPath
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.getPermissions CeilingPolicy allPerms
security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: http://portail-rep/LanceAppli.jar
security: Valider la chaîne de certificats à laide de lAPI CertPath
security: SSV validation:
    running: 1.7.0_55
    requested: null
    range: null
    javaVersionParam: null
    Rule Set version: null
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.55
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.55
security: continue with running version
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.55
network: Created version ID: 1.7
network: Created version ID: 2.2.55
basic: Applet chargée.
basic: Applet redimensionnée et ajoutée au conteneur parent
basic: PERF: AppletExecutionRunnable - applet.init() BEGIN ; jvmLaunch dt 607006 us, pluginInit dt 4585715 us, TotalTime: 5192721 us
basic: Applet initialisée
basic: Démarrage de l'applet
basic: cumul des performances effectué
basic: Applet rendue visible
basic: Applet démarrée
basic: Les clients ont été informés que l'applet est démarrée
```

After this first load, close firefox and restart firefox : the applet not loaded, java is waiting to connect.
This is the log when java is waiting to connexion :

```
cache: Initialize resource manager: com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl@1353d27
security:  --- parseCommandLine converted : -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
into:
[-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true]
basic: Processus d'écoute de progression ajouté : sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@1d7a082
security: Expected Main URL: http://portail-rep/LanceAppli.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://portail-rep/LanceAppli.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://portail-rep/LanceAppli.jar
security: La vérification de révocation de la liste noire est activée
security: blacklist: created: NEED_LOAD, lastModified: 1399896272597
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1399896272623 (we have 1399896272597)
security: La vérification de liste de bibliothèques sécurisées est activée
network: Entrée de cache trouvée [URL : http://portail-rep/LanceAppli.jar, version : null] prevalidated=false/0
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: http://portail-rep/LanceAppli.jar
cache: Resource http://portail-rep/LanceAppli.jar has expired.
network: Connexion de http://portail-rep/LanceAppli.jar avec proxy=DIRECT
network: Connexion de http://portail-rep:80/ avec proxy=DIRECT
```

The connexion never acheved and firefox crash.

Precision : 
- JRE 1.7.0_55-b14
- Plug-in Java 10.55.2.14
- the domain name portail-rep is an apache virtual host pointing on localhost.

There is no trace of LanceAppli.jar in the acces.log file of apache when calling test.htm the second time. So java can not join apache the second time.

Here is the html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
<object width="300" height="300" name="apExec"
        archive="LanceAppli.jar"
        type="application/x-java-applet"
        classid="java:irsn/LanceAppli.class"
        id="apExec">
    <param name="java_arguments" value="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" />
    <param name="archive" value="LanceAppli.jar" />
    <param name="code" value="irsn/LanceAppli.class" />
    <param name="cache_archive" value="LanceAppli.jar" />
</object>
</body>
</html>
```

More precision : all the same when test.htm located at the root of apache, called by `http://localhost/test.htm`

Is the applet code could be useful to solve this problem? If so I can provide it.